# Using GoDaddy as Proxy Server

Tags: proxy, webserver

I would like to use my shared web hosting on a big provider (like GoDaddy) as a proxy for web browsing. Is this possible? Any links or advice for how to get started doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a PHP-based proxy named [PHProxy / poxy at SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/poxy/).

I've successfully run this at GoDaddy, but you may run into bandwidth and script execution time-out limits for big files. Works OK for browsing sites.

If you're planning on using the proxy for anonymity/privacy purposes, I would suggest using [TOR](http://www.torproject.org/) instead, since the GoDaddy logs may be seized and used as evidence in various jurisdictions.

Comment: Thank you for that. I would +1 you but I don't have the rep :)

Comment: Problem is I would love to stream HBO and that kind of stuff from the US, since I would be there but I'm not :) I think that would be a bandwidth problem.